# jQuery stop animation on click

Tags: jquery

How do I stop the following from happening when I click on another button?

```
box_2.animate({'top':'-250px'},500,function(){                                                      overlay.fadeOut('fast');
                                 });
```

Comment: [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('button').click(function() {
    box_2.stop(true,true);
})
```